# Mongo DB filter query not working for nodejs, express mongoose app stack

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I have tried using mongoose query to filter out mongodb documents which have certain attributes qualifying a certain criteria.

---

Case1) Without filter my call looks lie below,

---

```
const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();

let Post = require('./post.model');

postRoutes.route('/fetchlabdetails').get(function (req, res) {
    
    Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = postRoutes;
```

---

Output : On hitting localhost:4000/fetchlabdetails, it return json object with 2 nodes as expected

```
[{"listoftests":[{"test1":300,"test2":500,"test3":200}],"_id":"5f4235ff3b89c00a6834bf93","labid":"100"},{"listoftests":[{"test4":300,"test5":500,"test6":200}],"_id":"5f4282253b89c00a6834bf94","labid":"101"}]
```

Case2) With filter

```
const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();

let Post = require('./post.model');

postRoutes.route('/fetchlabdetails').get(function (req, res) {
    
    Post.find({labid:100},function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = postRoutes;
```

Output: Null JSON object

I would like to filter out data on basis of value of labid.  I have also attached nodejs server configuration file and model.js file for schema.

FYI i have tried below combinations as well which wont work

```
Post.find({'labid':100},function(err, posts)
Post.find({'labid':'100'},function(err, posts)
```

Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declared wrong datatype for labid attribute. Changing it solved the problem